# Three.js select GLTF object from a dropdown with DAT.gui

Tags: three.js, dat.gui

I started messing about with Three.js a couple of months ago.
I have basic js knowledge, most of the code was adapted from the **Three.js Examples**.

I want to load a model selected from a dropdown list.
There is only one model displayed at once, so I didnt want to add a new gltf loader for each model.
I have 1 gltf loader and I want to change the path based upon the option the user selects from the dropdown.

**VARIABLES**

```
let pathSelected, pathHe, pathCat, pathGears; 
pathHe = ('./MODEL/he.gltf');      
pathCat = ('./MODEL/cat/cat.gltf');                    
pathGears = ('./MODEL/gears/gears.gltf');
```

.....

**GLTF LOADER**

```
function init() {
...
  loader = new GLTFLoader();
  loader.load(pathSelected, function (gltf) {
    gltf.scene.traverse(function (child) {
      if (child.isMesh) {
        children.push(child);
      }
    });
...
}
```

**DAT.GUI PANEL**

```
function createPanel() {
...
var objSelector = objectShow.add(settings, 'modelOptions', ["HE", "Cat", "Gear Box"]).name("Seclect").listen();

  objSelector.onChange(function (value) {
    var value = settings.modelOptions;
    if (value == "Heat Exchanger") {
      pathSelected = pathHe;
      console.log('Dropdown: HE', pathSelected);
    }
    else if (value == "Cat") {
      pathSelected = pathCat;
      console.log('Dropdown: Cat', pathSelected);
    }
    else if (value == "Gear Box") {
      pathSelected = pathGears;
      console.log('Dropdown: Cat', pathSelected);
    }
    else { ... }
  });
...
}
```

**DEMO:**
https://mellowmonks.in/demos/9/

**PW:** MellowMonk@123

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Comment: The demo link in the question is password protected. Nevertheless, three.js examples has a similar one for ldraw loader: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_ldraw The syntax would be the same for gltf loader too

Comment: Thanks for the pointing in the right direction. @Deep
The example does exactly what I want to achieve. Will fiddle around with the example code.